# Traer una fila que no esta en una de las 2 tablas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo esta consulta en sql

```
SELECT 
    SI_Articulo = COALESCE(t.SI_Articulo, c.SI_Num_Articulo),
    SI_Ubicacion = COALESCE(t.SI_Ubicacion, c.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_OV = COALESCE(c.SI_OV,''),
    SI_Ubicacion_Fisica = COALESCE(c.SI_Ubicacion_Fisica,''),
    SI_Existencia = COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Cantidad = COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0), 
    SI_Cantidad2 = (SELECT COALESCE(c2.SI_Cantidad,0) 
        FROM SI_Conteo c2 
        WHERE  c2.SI_Num_Conteo = 2 /*AND c2.SI_Num_Articulo = 200002*/
            AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c2.SI_Ubicacion),
    SI_Dif =  COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad, 0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia, 0),
    SI_Dif_Dinero = (COALESCE(c.SI_Cantidad,0) - COALESCE(t.SI_Existencia,0)) * COALESCE(m.SI_Costo_Promedio,0)  
FROM SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD t 
LEFT JOIN SI_Conteo c
    ON (t.SI_Articulo = c.SI_Num_Articulo 
        AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1
        AND t.SI_Ubicacion = c.SI_Ubicacion)
INNER JOIN SI_Maestro_Ref_QAD m 
    ON (t.SI_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo 
        OR c.SI_Num_Articulo = m.SI_Num_Articulo) 
WHERE c.SI_Num_Articulo = 200002 
    OR t.SI_Articulo = 200002
```

La cual me trae el siguiente resultado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi problema esta es que en la tabla `SI_Conteo` tengo la misma referencia agregada, pero no existe en la tabla `SI_SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD` por lo tanto no me la muestra.

y no puedo poner `FULL JOIN` O `FULL OUTER JOIN` Por que tambien existe el mismo articulo pero ya con `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2` entonces me trae todo y no solo lo de `AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1`

Esta es la que no me trae

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de usar LEFT JOIN para la relación entre **SI_SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD -> SI_Conteo**, utiliza FULL OUTER JOIN, así en caso de no existir dicha relación en alguna de las dos tablas traerá lo especificado en tu **COALESCE**:

```
...
FULL OUTER JOIN SI_Conteo c
...
```

Si tienes inconvenientes con registros por el lado de la primera tabla, utiliza RIGHT JOIN.

Comment: El prome de poner FULL OUTER JOIN es que me trae los que esten en `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2` y solo necesito mostrar los que estan en `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1`

Comment: En ese caso, utiliza RIGHT JOIN para que así solo tomes en cuenta los registros de la tabla derecha, así como edite en la respuesta.

Comment: Si utilizo el `RIGHT JOIN` pasa lo mismo que si utilizara `FULL OUTER JOIN` es como si me estuviera ignorando `AND c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1`

Comment: Claro, no me había fijado que tienes condiciones en el ON, primero que nada tengo entendido que eso no se debe hacer, ya que no las va a respetar y son de mala práctica. Ubica dichas condiciones en el WHERE (ya que por lo visto se deben cumplir si o si) y verás que funciona!. Cualquier cosa no dudes en comentar.

Comment: No te entiendo bien.

Comment: En los ON de los JOINS no debes usar condicionantes con parametros, por ejemplo: c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1, en vez de ponerlo en el ON, utilizalo en el WHERE, quedandote asi:
WHERE (c.SI_Num_Articulo = 200002 
    OR t.SI_Articulo = 200002) and c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1

Comment: Funciono pero ahora me quito el que esta en la Ubicacion `TRANSCLI`, sera por que la ubicacion `TRANSCLI`  esta en la tabla `SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD`  y no en la tabla `SI_Conteo`

Comment: Tu COALCE está contemplando eso, en caso de no estar en una da null, por lo que toma el valor de la otra. Debe ser otra cosa. Puede ser el mismo c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1 no se cumple en esa ubicación, por lo que no te lo muestra.

Comment: Alguna sugerencia para que me traiga la `Ubicacion`   `TRANSCLI` por que si le quito el ` c.SI_Num_Conteo = 1` tambien me trae los que esten en `c.SI_Num_Conteo = 2`

Comment: Verificaste que en la tabla SI_Conteo el registro con SI_Ubicacion = TRANSCLI, tenga como SI_Num_Conteo = 1? o cual es el SI_Num_Conteo que tiene ese registro?

Comment: SI_Num_Conteo = 1 solo esta en la tabla SI_Conteo, Y la Ubicacion TRANSCLI esta en la tabla SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD la cual no tiene SI_Num_Conteo = 1

Comment: aaah ok ! entonces ya no seria RIGHT JOIN, cambialo por FULL OUTER JOIN y listo. El problema es que estaba excluyendo a SI_Inventario_Teorico_QAD. Saludos!